# Opencart question regarding square feet and boxes needed calculator

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I am creating a website in Opencart that sells flooring, and they need me to create a field in which the buyer can put the amount o square feet needed, and then the "system" will tell them how many boxes to purchase.

this is simple enough anywhere else that is not Openncart, I would just grab the element where the product list its square feet per box and do the appropriate function.

The issue that I am having, is that Opencart uses PHP and there is no static place where this number resides.

I tried adding a class to the specifications table on the product twig, however, since technically there are no tables until it already initializes in the html, all I was able t do was add class="sqft" to every  it created.

For instance, in the Twig it merely says  {{attribute.name}}  which is pulling from PHP I imagine. So I put  {{attribute.name}}  and the html rendered all my attributes with  even those that were not square footage like a width attribute. Example  width< /td>  5.5" wide

There is no where else for me to put the square footage per box on the product, so I am at a loss how to grab this information so that the user themselves to not have to enter their square footage that they need AND the products square foot per box.

So far also, I have looked up different extensions and a few ideas on stack, but none of the dealt with boxes..only create a square footage calculator ( length x width etc ).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Opencart 3.x

This is also my first question on Stack, so I I missed any needed information or came across as anything that gets on your nerves I apologize.

EDIT:

I figured it out. Since the square feet per box changed depending on the product, the option227 or option228 could not be used with getElementById, so I instead used querySelector, which only grabbed the optoin part NOT the numbered product.

worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an attribute for the sq. ft. per box: http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/catalog/product/attribute/

Then you should get that attribute in the product controller and set it as a variable that you can output to JavaScript, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var sq_ft_per_box = 24</script>
```

You can then write some JavaScript elsewhere that takes the number the customer puts in to an input and divide it by the variable set above to give the number they should purchase. Of course you should round up to give whole boxes.

Comment: I did try options but the options array changes for each product, so now I am trying  yuour method but I do not see where to put in that script in the controller.

Comment: JavaScript goes in the view not the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I working with opencart website few days ago width, length

```
<script>

    function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;

         document.getElementById('result').value = myResult;

         var main = myResult * 5/100;

         var main_total = myResult + main;

         document.getElementById('result1').value = main_total;
    }

</script>
```

I think is working fine and you can understand some logic. if you are developer

Thanks for asking to me

Comment: The issue was that the "box1" was dynamic, the square feet per box changed depending on what product was clicked on, so it couldn't find it anymore. I solved it by using a queryselector instead.